# Swift: Write data how to know when complete Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

I want to write a data image on the computer, it works. But I would like to know if there is a way to know if the file was written? A completion handler?

My code:

```
let bMImg = NSBitmapImageRep(data: (resizedImage.tiffRepresentation)!)
    let dataToSave = bMImg?.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.png, properties: [NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey.compressionFactor: 1])
    do {
        try dataToSave?.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

I want to know if it's possible to be informed when `dataToSave?.write(to: fileURL)` has finished writing, Because I have to write several files at the same time using the recursive method, so I need a way to know if it was written so that I could start the recursive

I can not find a method with completion handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data`'s `write(to:options:)` method is synchronous. When it returns, the operation has completed (or failed if it threw an error). If you need to write asynchronously, dispatch to another queue or create your own `Thread` to perform the write.